# Recyclerview not populating in asynctask android

Tags: android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have two methods which I need to run asynchronously in android.First I want to run getContactsList() and then populateList().I tried to use Asynctask but it skips the recyclerview populating code and then prints the next line in the log while it works well in onCreate.Please help me

```
 private class TaskOne extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("do in background", "running");
        getContactList();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pDialog.cancel();
        Log.i("onPostExecute", "running");
        populateList();
        isContacts_fetched();
        Log.i("populateList", "finished");


    }
}
```

calling in onCreate() methods

```
new TaskOne().execute();
```

populateList() code

```
 public void populateList() {
```

Log.i("Populate List","Entered");

```
//        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(Common.selectedContactNos.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   displayRecyclerAdapter = new DisplayRecyclerAdapter(DisplayContacts.this);
   LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView_contacts.setAdapter(displayRecyclerAdapter);
   recyclerView_contacts.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
   displayRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: How is displayRecyclerAdapter referring to the list? Are you passing the list in the constructor?

Comment: the recyclerview works well when I run it in onCreate().It is only not running when I am passing in asynctask.The list is being saved in an arraylist in a static class and being being in recyclerview

Comment: Not really sure about the issue. Would need more code to be able to help. Can you check the size of list in the adapter? Also try using the below code for populating adapter : recyclerView_contacts.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                populateList();
            }
        })